# Synchronizing a member variable of a class

Tags: java, multithreading

I am learning Threads. While learning I came across a scenario where a static variable is used by two threads.

I want synchronous behavior between two threads.

Here is my code:

```
package com.learning.fizzbuzz;

public class Trigger {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Solution s = new Solution("thread1");
        s.start(20);

        Solution s1 = new Solution("thread2");
        s1.start(15);

    }

}

package com.learning.fizzbuzz;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Solution implements Runnable{

    private Thread t;

    private String threadName;

    private static int n;

    public Solution(String threadName) {
        this.threadName = threadName;
        System.out.println("Creating thread :: "+ threadName);
    }

    public static List<String> fizzBuzz(int n) {

        List<String> elements = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
            if (i % (15) == 0) {
                elements.add("FizzBuzz");
            }
            else if (i % 3 == 0) {
                elements.add("Fizz");
            }
            else if (i % 5 == 0) {
                elements.add("Buzz");
            }
            else {
                elements.add(String.valueOf(i));
            }
        }

        return elements;
    }

    public static String reverseString(String s) {
        StringBuffer str = new StringBuffer(s);
        s = str.reverse().toString();
        return s;
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void run() {
            System.out.println("Executing thread :: " + threadName);
            List<String> str = fizzBuzz(n);
            System.out.println(str +" :: "+ t.getName());
            System.out.println(reverseString("Hello") +" :: "+ t.getName());
    }

    public void start(int num) {
        if (t == null) {
            System.out.println("Starting thread :: " + threadName);
            t = new Thread(this, threadName);
            Solution.n = num;
            System.out.println("number is " + n);
            t.start();
        } else {
            System.out.println("Thread Already Created and Running :: " + threadName);
        }
    }
}
```

I tried synchronizing various blocks of the Solution class but was not able to obtain a result as mentioned below.

> [1, 2, Fizz, 4, Buzz, Fizz, 7, 8, Fizz, Buzz, 11, Fizz, 13, 14,
>   FizzBuzz, 16, 17, Fizz, 19, Buzz] :: thread2 olleH :: thread2
>
> [1, 2, Fizz, 4, Buzz, Fizz, 7, 8, Fizz, Buzz, 11, Fizz, 13, 14,
>   FizzBuzz] :: thread1 olleH :: thread1

Please advise.

**EDIT : One thing that I observed is the value of n is set to 15 before both threads start executing. How to avoid that?**

Comment: What exactly is the behavior you want?

Comment: first thread should print 20 elements in array.
second thread should print 15 elements in array.

Comment: You should use an instance variable to get that result.

Comment: @Bubletan Can you please explain a little more in detail? Thanks.

Comment: @tushar Remove the `static` modifier from `n`. Then both `Solution`s have their own value for it instead of using the same one.

Comment: as well, after making n non-static and also change Solution constructor to accept n as parameter, you don't really need fizzBuzz to be static or have n as a parameter.

Comment: @Bubletan That worked. But what happens exactly when we remove static?

Comment: @tushar When using a static variable you first set it to 20 and then change it to 15. This may or may not happen before the first thread accesses it. With a non-static variable both instances will have their own value; the 20 and the 15 will be stored at different memory locations.

Comment: @Bubletan Thanks. I now got the clarity on how static keyword behaves on a variable.

Answer (score 0):

To access a static shared variable you need to synchronize two (or more) threads on the same monitor.

This can't be done using the keyword `synchronized` on a method instance because it synchronize on the variable `this`.

The simplest way is to synchronize using a static variable.

```
public class MyClass {
    private static Object lock = new Object();

    private static int sharedVariable;

    public void yourMethod() {

        synchronized(lock) {
           // Do something with sharedVariable
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: It does work, just not for what you are trying to do. "Synchronizing" here means that only one thread can enter and execute the code in the synchronized block. But even if you do this, you still have one variable that you want to hold two separate values.